# How to modify the branch protection rule in GitHub to merge the pull requests created from a feature branch with specific name pattern

Tags: git, github, devops, git-branch

I have a master branch in my GitHub repo. I would like to apply some branch protection rule to the master so that the pull requests will be merged to master only if the pull requests are created from a specific name pattern of feature branches (eg : the PR should be merged only if the feature branch name starts with test_patch/*)

In github branch protection rules section there is no option to restrict the merge pull request for a specific pattern, but they have option for specific users or teams.

Comment: Side Note, branches can be created and renamed easily to point to any commit, so even if you succeed in doing what you ask, it doesn't really provide any "protection" other than a naming convention convenience.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe GitHub offers such a policy.  However, it's not too hard to set up such a policy yourself.

You can create a CI job, such as a GitHub Action, that looks at the source branch name and the destination branch name, and if the destination branch is `master` and the source branch doesn't match the pattern, then fail the CI job.  If you set that CI job as required in the branch protection settings (which you can do once it's run for the first time), the PR won't be able to be merged.

That doesn't prevent you from opening such a PR, which might result in a lot of inconvenient duplicate work if they typo the branch by accident, but it does prevent it from being merged.